# Apply a function to each group of a RDD

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a very big file which contains informations about football players.
I already splitted the file into multiple groups and assign each line of each group to a header.

So this RDD is structured like following.

With the code :

```
for groupId, zippedGroup in zippedRDD.collect():
    print("Group ID:", groupId)
    g=0
    for line in zippedGroup:
        if g!=10:
            print(line)
            g=g+1
    print("-----------------")
```

I got the output :

```
Group ID: 5
('Player ID', 'AdIOxQkdr')
('Name', 'AdIOxQkdr')
('Position', '0')
('Jersey Number', '0')
('Nationality', '2')
('Age', '-9')
('Goal Scored', 'AGAA AGAA')
('Assists', 'CAACTAGTT CAACTAGTT')
('Yellow Cards', 'TT TT')
('Red Cards', 'TC TC')
Group ID: 2
('Player ID', 'pOKFAC')
('Name', 'pOKFAC')
('Position', '0')
('Jersey Number', '0')
('Nationality', '2')
('Age', '-9')
('Goal Scored', 'AGAA AGAA')
('Assists', 'CAACTAGTT CAACTAGTT')
('Yellow Cards', 'TT TT')
('Red Cards', 'TC TC')
Group ID: 3
('Player ID', 'tGWo')
('Name', 'tGWo')
('Position', '0')
('Jersey Number', '0')
('Nationality', '2')
('Age', '-9')
('Goal Scored', 'AGAA AGAA')
('Assists', 'CAACTAGTT CAACTAGTT')
('Yellow Cards', 'TT TT')
('Red Cards', 'TC TC')
Group ID: 4
('Player ID', 'd8F6')
('Name', 'd8F6')
('Position', '0')
('Jersey Number', '0')
('Nationality', '2')
('Age', '-9')
('Goal Scored', 'AGAA AGAA')
('Assists', 'CAACTAGTT CAACTAGTT')
('Yellow Cards', 'TT TT')
('Red Cards', 'TC TC')
Group ID: 1
('Player ID', 'xbSH')
('Name', 'xbSH')
('Position', '0')
('Jersey Number', '0')
('Nationality', '2')
('Age', '-9')
('Goal Scored', 'AGAA AGAA')
('Assists', 'CAACTAGTT CAACTAGTT')
('Yellow Cards', 'TT TT')
('Red Cards', 'TC TC')
```

I would like to add the informations about the player ( so the first 6 values of each group) to all the tuples afters those 6 tuple. For example, I would like to get for the group 5 :

```
('Player ID', 'AdIOxQkdr')
('Name', 'AdIOxQkdr')
('Position', '0')
('Jersey Number', '0')
('Nationality', '2')
('Age', '-9')
('AdIOxQkdr','AdIOxQkdr','0','0','2','-9','Goal Scored', 'AGAA AGAA')
('AdIOxQkdr','AdIOxQkdr','0','0','2','-9','Assists', 'CAACTAGTT CAACTAGTT')
('AdIOxQkdr','AdIOxQkdr','0','0','2','-9','Yellow Cards', 'TT TT')
('AdIOxQkdr','AdIOxQkdr','0','0','2','-9','Red Cards', 'TC TC').
```

Then, I would like to save this rdd into CSV.

I tried first to tranfer only the player ID to all the tuples after the sixth but it did not work properly :

```
transformedRDD = zippedRDD.flatMap(lambda element: [(element[1][0], tuple[0], tuple[1]) for tuple in element[6:]])
```

It did not work properly.
I am now a bit lost and I would love to get some help.

Comment: Don't you think that it is better to work with dataframes ? you can construct it from your rdd and then use the available functions, use spark.sql methods ect..